# VBA multiply two named ranges

Tags: excel, vba, variables, range

I've been trying to look this up everywhere and I can't seem to find the answer or get it to work.

I have the code

```
'Define Variables for cell ranges'
Dim BidItem As Range
Dim BidItemDes As Range
Dim BidItemUnit As Range
Dim BidItemQTY As Range
Dim BidItemUP As Range

'Store the sheet range into the variables'
Set BidItem = Sheets("BidItems").Range("A1:A" & Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row)
Set BidItemDes = Sheets("BidItems").Range("B1:B" & Range("B1").End(xlDown).Row)
Set BidItemUnit = Sheets("BidItems").Range("C1:C" & Range("C1").End(xlDown).Row)
Set BidItemQTY = Sheets("BidItems").Range("D1:D" & Range("D1").End(xlDown).Row)       
Set BidItemUP = Sheets("BidItems").Range("E1:E" & Range("E1").End(xlDown).Row)
Set BidItemValue = Sheets("BidItems").Range("F1:F" & Range("F1").End(xlDown).Row)

Set BidItemValue = Sheets("BidItems").Range("F1:F" & Range("F1").End(xlDown).Row)
```

What I need to do is have all the data in range BidItemQTY and Multiply it by the range BidItemUP
and then output that answer to the range BidItemValue.

I have the last line of code setup to start the function but
I can't seem to grasp on how to do math functions in VBA with Variables.

Comment: Can't you just manually add a formula in column F and drag down? `=$D1*$E1`

Answer (score 2):

Consider this tiny example:

```
Sub dural()
    Dim second As Range
    Dim first As Range, prodt As Long

    Set first = Range("A1:A3")
    Set second = Range("B1:B3")
    prodt = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumProduct(first, second)

    MsgBox prodt
End Sub
```

[image]

**EDIT#1:**

To get the individual products stored in cells, use:

```
Sub dural()
    Dim second As Range
    Dim first As Range, prodt As Long
    Dim third As Range

    Set first = Range("A1:A3")
    Set second = Range("B1:B3")
    Set third = Range("C1:C3")

    For i = 1 To 3
        third(i, 1) = first(i, 1) * second(i, 1)
    Next i

End Sub
```

[image]

***Notes:***

- since the ranges are not single cells, we treat them as two-dimensional
- it may be possible to avoid the loop using *Transpose()*
- in this case the one-dimensional will also work:

```
For i = 1 To 3
        third(i) = first(i) * second(i)
Next i
```

Comment: Looking at Dans code I'd have thought he wants an individual value for each item as the `BidItemValue` variable covers a number of cells in column F.  I could be wrong though, in which case SUMPRODUCT is definitely the answer.

Comment: Yes I'm looking for it to add each row by itself IE: F2 = D2*E2, F3 = D3 *E3 and so on

Comment: @DanLopes See my **EDIT#1:**

Comment: Made some changes and now getting an error. Need the formulas to start on row 2. Also is there a way I can reference the named ranges listed in the OP as opposed to a set cell reference?                                                                                                        Sub dural()
    Dim second As Range
    Dim first As Range, prodt As Long
    Dim third As Range

    Set first = Range("D2:D1000")
    Set second = Range("E2:C1000")
    Set third = Range("F2:F1000")

    For i = 2 To 1000
        third(i, 1) = first(i, 1) * second(i, 1)
    Next i

End Sub

Comment: solved it Set second = Range("E2:C1000")  should be E2:E1000 been a long day missed something so simple, still want to know about using the named ranges though.

Comment: @DanLopes  To use a **Named Range**, use something like `Set third = Range("somerange")`